# window.open returns null on windows phone 8

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am currently working on a hyrbid mobile app for windows phone 8.0 and windows phone 8.1 using the cordova framework. There is a scenario where I need to use the in-app browser to launch a login page.

I used the following javascript code .

```
var authWindow = window.open('http://www.mylogin.com', 'mywindow', 'location=yes,toolbar=yes,clearsessioncache=yes');
```

Although the window opens fine I am getting null as the reference to the window object here. I need the reference to perform other actions on the opened window.

On further research I found that issue exists in desktop IE11 also and we have to disable the protected mode. Once I did it and ran the code on desktop  IE11 it worked fine.

I am not sure how to achieve the same in my scenario. Is there any setting I need to change on the browser control? How do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Open external pages on Windows Phone as a Javascript Mobile App is a real problem. On Android and IOS you just use "windows.open" and you are good to go. But on WP, we will need to **create a C# plugin.**

On my app, I did the following:

*1 - You will need a javascript function that calls the plugin.*

**Javascript call**

```
function openExternalURL(theURL) {
    cordova.exec(function () { }, function () { }, "yourApp.main.plugins.YourPluginClass", "openURLWithNative", [theURL);
};
```

*2 - Now you need to implement a C# class that calls Windows Phone browser with the correct URL. For it, you should create a .cs file (in the example its name is YourPluginClass.cs):*

**YourPluginClass.cs (C#)**

```
namespace yourApp.main.plugins
{
    class YourPluginClass : BaseCommand
    {
         public void openURLWithNative(string uri)
        {
            WebBrowserTask task = new WebBrowserTask();
            string optVal = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(uri)[0];

            task.Uri = new Uri(optVal);
            task.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you can open any external URL on Windows Phone like Android and IOS.

Hope it helps. Best Regards!

Answer (score 0):

There is a few good workaroungs that worked for me in :

Do a `window.open("about:blank", "newPage");` before the `AJAX` call and then after the call add the URL to the opened window by calling `window.open("http://google.com", "newPage");`.